# How to get API using axios in nuxt.js?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to get API information and set the data-table.
But my code has error.
Error messages are below in console.

> Property or method "items" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Please someone advise me?

and also my English is not good so please someone help my question to correctly English.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-data-table dense :headers="headers" :item="items" class="elevation-1"></v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "nuxt-property-decorator";
import axios from "axios";

@Component
export default class AxiosPractice extends Vue {
  items: object[] = [];

  headers = [
    { text: "id", value: "postId" },
    { text: "name", value: "name" },
    { text: "email", value: "email" }
  ];
  async mounted() {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments"
    );
    this.itmes = response.data.map((comment:any) => ({
      postId: comment.postId,
      email: comment.email,
      name: comment.name
    }));
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try not to mix `await` with `then()`, it just makes things confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that `response` is an object that contains the property `data` (see [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema)) which (in this case) holds an array of objects.
Assuming you want to save postId, email and name for every comment in `items`, you could try this:

```
const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments');

this.items = response.data.map(comment => ({
  postId: comment.postId,
  email: comment.email,
  name: comment.name,
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code, but had error.

Comment: itmes : ⇒Property 'items' does not exist on type 'AxiosPractice'. Did you mean 'itmes'

Comment: comment⇒Parameter 'comment' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: I really understand your explanations and i really appreciated it. Could you explain about error.please??

Comment: You have a typo in items: `itmes:object`.

Comment: Mr.sandrooco 
like that below?
this.items:object[] = response.data.map(comment => ({
          postId: comment.postId,
          email: comment.email,
          name: comment.name

Comment: I wouldn‘t use that object[] typing, rather a proper interface. But yes, that could work.

Comment: Mr.sandorooco. Thank you so much for many comments. I'm sorry it did not work yet. so i edit my question referred your code. but still same error messages displayed in console. Could you check my code again?

Comment: Now you have `items` on your component but try to set `this.itmes`...

Comment: Mr.sandorooco.Thanks ! I got it!!

Comment: sorry I forgot. Now, I thought I accepted your answer. is it Ok ??

Comment: Yes, thanks. This helps the community to not try to solve already solved questions.